# Assign a string to a struct via reflect

Tags: go, reflection, heap-memory

I have a struct, where I wish to dynamically change a string to another string using reflect. My issue is that the new string is created on the stack, and therefore the Set() method panics.

This makes sense to me, but I don't know *how* to fix it. I'm not sure the easy way to declare a string as addressable or if there's a different reflection technique to use.

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    SomeField string
}

func main() {
    myStruct := MyStruct{"initial"}
    hello := "hello world"
    
    field := reflect.ValueOf(myStruct).FieldByName("SomeField")
    helloValue := reflect.ValueOf(hello)
    fmt.Printf("hello is on the stack, canAddr is %v\n", helloValue.CanAddr())
    
    // This will panic because canAddr is false
    field.Set(helloValue)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ghUgiQfKXhk

Comment: You cannot make something that is not addressable, addressable (while it may be stack allocated, that's unrelated to this from a language perspective). You can however use a pointer to the value you want to address, which in this case is `myStruct`, not `hello`.

Answer (score 2):

The go error is a bit of a misnomer. The problem is with the struct, not the string.

The problem is in this line:
`field := reflect.ValueOf(myStruct).FieldByName("SomeField")`
Calling `ValueOf` passes in a copy (of myStruct in this case). Since changing a copy won't change myStruct, then go panics (helpfully, if cryptically). See [the third law of reflection] (https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection#TOC_8)

Changing this line to `field := reflect.ValueOf(&myStruct).Elem().FieldByName("SomeField")` fixes the error (note the & to take the address, and then Elem() to dereference)

Of course I only figure this out after posting the question but hopefully it will help someone else